# preg_replace not replacing underscore

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to allow only alpha numeric characters and spaces, so I use the following;

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z0-9 ]/', '', $str);
```

However, that is allowing underscores "_" which I don't want. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [character class](https://www.php.net/manual/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) range is for a range of characters between two code points. The character `_` is included in the range `A-z`, and you can see this by looking at the ASCII table:

```
... Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b ...
```

So it's not only the underscore that's being let through, but those other characters you see above, as stated in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/regexp.reference.character-classes.php):

> Ranges operate in ASCII collating sequence. ... For example, `[W-c]` is equivalent to `[][\^_```wxyzabc]`.

To prevent this from happening, you can perform a case insensitive match with a single character range in your character class:

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]/i', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your expression. Last Z must be capital.

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/', '', $str);
                              ^
```